# Study the convergence of this succession

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help with this exercise.

> $$ U_n=\frac{n \times cos(n \pi)}{2n+1} $$

What I've done so far is recognize the main difficulty of the problem which is the $cos(n\pi)$, an alternating term due to the fact that it can only go until number $1$ and $-1$ back again.

> $$ U_n=\frac{n}{2n+1}\times cos(n \pi) $$

Writing the exercise like this, gives a little perspective of what it should be done to know if the succession does really converge.

My problem is that I don't know if I should do the limit of the non-alternating term (to figure out if it converges or not) or if I should just finish the exercise by saying that, because of the $cos(n\pi)$, the succession has a limit and, therefore, it converges.

Thank you so much
If someone could help I would really appreciate it

Comment: Compute the limits of $(U_{2n})_n$ and $(U_{2n+1})_n$. They exist; are they the same? What does that tell you?

Comment: Because they don't tend to the same limit, the succession does not converge, right?

Comment: Indeed. If the sequence did converge to some $L$, then all subsequence would converge to $L$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider the subsequences for

- $n=2k \implies U_{2k}=\frac{2k \times cos(2k \pi)}{4k+1}=\frac{2k}{4k+1}\to \frac12$
- $n=2k+1 \implies U_{2k+1}=\frac{(2k+1) \times cos(2k \pi+\pi)}{4k+2}=\frac{-(2k+1)}{4k+2}\to -\frac12$

and note that those subsequences tend to different limits.

Then remember that if limit exists all the subsequecens tend to the same limit (i.e. it is a **necessary condition** for the existence of the limit).

Comment: Sorry for the basic question but...... I'm not being able to calculate the limit with those 'k'. Are they just representations of rational numbers?
Could you help me a little bit more?  (successions isn't really my scene and I'm having trouble understanding it....)

Comment: @Agapita Note that 2k means fo n even and 2k+1 means n odd, I add some details but the important issue us about the necessary condition, it is the standar way to show that limit doesn't exist, thus it is important to be aware about it

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it so much better now :)

Comment: @Agapita You are welcome, keep in mind this theorem!